# Inequality for a parabolic pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

I am trying to solve the following exercise.
Consider the linear parabolic equation
\begin{equation}
\partial _t u -\nabla (A(x,t)\nabla u)=f(x,t), x \in \Omega,t>0,
\end{equation}
subject to the initial data $u(x,0)=u_0(x)$ for $x\in\Omega$, where the diffusion matrix A satisfies
\begin{equation}
\xi ^{-1}|y|^2\leq \sum _{i,j =1} ^n A _{i,j}(x,t)y_i y_j\leq\xi|y|^2, x\in\Omega,t>0,\forall y \in R^n
\end{equation}
for some $\epsilon>0$.
Let $f\equiv 0$ and consider the Neumann boundary condition $(A(x,t)\nabla u(x,t))\nu=0$for $x\in\partial\Omega$. Show that
\begin{equation}
\lVert u(t)-\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int _{\Omega} u_0(x) dx\rVert _{L^2(\Omega)}\leq Ce^{- \mu t}
\end{equation}
for some $C,\mu >0$.

I tried the following.

First I subtracted the mean value of u over $\Omega$ from both sides of the equation and defined
\begin{equation}
v=u-\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int _{\Omega} u_0(x) dx.
\end{equation}
Then $v$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
\partial _t v-\nabla (A(x,t)\nabla v)=-\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int _{\Omega} \partial _t u_0(x) dx\ in\ \Omega \times (0,\infty)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v(x,0)=0\ in\ \Omega
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(A(x,t)\nabla v)n=0,\ on\ \partial\Omega
\end{equation}
I know from the first part of the exercise that
\begin{equation}
\lVert u(t) \rVert _{L^2(\Omega)}\leq Ce^{- \lambda t}
\end{equation}
for some $C,\lambda >0$.
Therefore, it holds that
\begin{equation}
\lVert v(t) \rVert _{L^2(\Omega)}\leq Ce^{- \lambda t}
\end{equation}
for some $C,\lambda >0$.
My next step was to combine the two results
\begin{equation}
C_p \lVert \nabla v(t)\rVert \geq \lVert v(t)\rVert \geq 0.
\end{equation}
This implies that $\nabla v=0$. Thus, $v$ is a constant function.
As the mean value of $v$ is zero, I know that $v\equiv 0$.
Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\lVert \lVert u(t)-\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int _{\Omega} u_0(x) dx\rVert\rVert _{L^2(\Omega)}=\lVert v(t)\rVert _{L^2(\Omega)}=0.
\end{equation}
This shows that
\begin{equation}
\lVert \lVert u(t)-\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int _{\Omega} u_0(x) dx\rVert\rVert _{L^2(\Omega)}\leq Ce^{\mu t}.
\end{equation}
Is my solution correct or are there any mistakes?

Comment: As the function $u_0$ does not depend on time, clearly $\partial_t u_0 = 0$, so why include it in your PDE for $v$. Secondly, the bound $\Vert u(t) \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq Ce^{-\lambda t}$ uses the Dirichlet boundary conditions, which we now do not have. Finally, where does $C_p \Vert \nabla v(t)\Vert \geq \Vert v(t) \Vert \geq 0$ come from? $v$ has neither zero mean value nor zero boundary conditions, and this inequality certainly doesn't imply that $\nabla v = 0$.

Comment: Additionally, $v(x,0) = 0$ is wrong, we have $v(x,0) = u_0(x) - \frac{1}{\vert\Omega\vert} \int_\Omega u_0(x)\,dx$.

Comment: Thank you! Could you show me how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v = u - \frac{1}{\vert\Omega\vert} \int_\Omega u_0(x) \,dx$. Then $v$ is a solution to
\begin{align*}
\partial_t v - \nabla\cdot(A\nabla v) &= 0 \quad \text{in} \ \Omega\times (0,\infty), \\
v(x,0) &= u_0(x) - \frac{1}{\vert\Omega\vert} \int_\Omega u_0(x) \,dx \quad \text{in} \ \Omega, \\
(A\nabla v )\cdot\nu &= 0 \quad\text{on}\ \partial\Omega\times (0,\infty).
\end{align*}
As $u$ is mass preserving, i.e.
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_\Omega u(t,x) \,dx = 0$$
for all $t > 0$ (Prove it!), we have in particular
$$ \int_\Omega u(t,x) \, dx = \int_\Omega u_0(x) \, dx$$
for all $t > 0$. This implies that
$$ \int_\Omega v(x,t) \,dx = \int_\Omega u(x,t) \,dx - \int_\Omega u_0(x) \, dx = 0$$
for all $t>0$. If we then define the energy $E:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $E(t) = \frac{1}{2} \int_\Omega v(t,x)^2 \,dx$, we obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} E(t) &= \int_\Omega v\partial_t v \,dx = - \int_\Omega A\nabla v \cdot\nabla v \, dx \\
&\leq - \frac{1}{\xi} \int_\Omega \vert\nabla v \vert^2 \, dx \\
&\leq -\frac{c}{\xi} \int_\Omega v^2 \, dx \\
&= -\frac{2c}{\xi} E(t).
\end{align}
Here we used the Poincare inequality, which is applicable since $\int_\Omega v \, dx = 0$. We conclude using Gronwall's inequality.